# Google maps not working on tablets

Tags: android, google-maps, tablet, android-location

I have the following code to open google map to get direction between two location. The code runs fine in all the phones that I have tested but it does not run in an of the tablets.

Below is my code: This is called when I click on a button (It crashes in tablets when I click on this button but runs fine on mobile phone)

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opening Google Map", 1).show();
 SharedPreferences carLocation = getSharedPreferences("CarLocation", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

 if(carLocation.contains("carlatitude")){
    //do nothing
 } else {
    showCurrentStatus = true;
 }

 AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> dostuff = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   try{
      if(mLocationClient.isConnected()){
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
      }
      mLocationClient.connect();
   }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
  return null;
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if(mLocationClient.isConnected()){
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
    }
};

};dostuff.execute();
```

And my onConnect is as follow:

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.d("MAinActivit","fetching current location");
    Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    double curLat = location.getLatitude();
    double curLong = location.getLongitude();

    SharedPreferences carLocation = getSharedPreferences("CarLocation", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    double carLat = Double.parseDouble(carLocation.getString("carlatitude", ""+curLat));
    double carLong = Double.parseDouble(carLocation.getString("carlongitude", ""+curLong));

    if(showCurrentStatus){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location", 0).show();
        showCurrentStatus = false;

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+curLat+","+curLong));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+curLat+","+curLong+"&daddr="+carLat+","+carLong));
        intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```